# What size frame is right for me?

Tags: frames, size

I have an inseam of around 26 1/2 inches (without shoes). Would a 47cm frame fit me? If not what would the correct frame size be? I'm looking for a hybrid (or road) bike.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the type of the bike and what you are going to use it for, its frame geometry and your body proportions. There are several bike fit calculators and size tables on the internet, perhaps some of them could help.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the only way to make sure you get a good fit is to sit on and test ride some bikes. There are many variables that sizing guides can't take into account, such as proportions of the rider's arms legs and torsos, and preferred riding position. Additionally, the common seat tube measurement isn't very standardized across manufacturers and frame styles

Getting the right size bike is worth putting some effort into. Presumably you want an bike you can enjoy riding, You won't enjoy riding an incorrectly sized bike. Even if you can manage one visit to a good bike shop to try a couple bikes would probably be worth it.

All of that said, if you really need to buy online, you definitely need at least a 'small' size. Look for manufacturer's size guides of bikes you are considering and for good return policies in case your estimate is off.

Answer (score 0):

For children you need 1" clearance between groin and bar for male.

For me it's about not raising the seat a mile to have my knee slightly bent when, ball of foot is on pedal and, pedal is down (proper seat adjustment). If you raise the seat high, the bars seem low. That is what matters to me. I don't like leaning forward. You need to test sizes in person and not by measurement. Does it feel comfortable? that is how to size.

Comment: I would love to be able to take the time to try before I buy, but my work schedule won't allow it. I'm left with the option of buying online.

Comment: Sorry I can't help then. It sounds like you would be a 21" bike. 26" would be big. Don't know cm's though.

Comment: @Elchanan Buying online is great for saving time and money.  But you run the significant risk of buying the wrong size.  You don't even know for sure if you want a road bike or a hybrid.  Try a decent bike shop and get your leg over a couple of sizes/styles/brands.

Comment: @Elchanan I don't understand. If you don't have time to shop for a bike, how will you have time to ride one?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Really?! To and from work.